# Skipping BeanValidator in ViewScoped beans with f:param nested in p:commandButton

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, bean-validation, view-scope

I'm using a BeanValidator (extending javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator) and in some cases I need to prevent the validation, since it's not necessary for some actions. My validator checks the request parameter map for a "validationBean" parameter with value "ignore_validation", and if it finds it, then the validation is skipped.

I'm having a hard time doing this in **ViewScoped** managed beans. I'm trying to skip the validation when clicking some buttons by doing this:

```
<p:commandButton id="button" icon="ui-icon-plusthick" onclick="createDialogWidget.show()">
    <f:param name="validationBean" value="ignore_validation"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

And in my BeanValidator I'm trying to get the parameter and skip the validation doing this:

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    String validationBean = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("validationBean");
    if (validationBean != null && validationBean.equals("ignore_validation")) {
            return;
    }
    ...
}
```

However, the "validationBean" variable above is null, i.e., the parameter wasn't found. Consequently, the validation is being performed.

Why isn't the parameter in the request parameter map? Is there anything wrong with this concept? Is there any other recommended way to skip the BeanValidator validation in some scenarios?

I'm using primefaces 3.2.4, Mojarra 2.1.2 and Tomcat 6.0.36.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how bean's scope would be related to this problem. Does the problem really disappear/change when you use request, session or application scope? As to the toggling bean validation, why don't you use the standard `<f:validateBean>` tag? You can just disable bean validation this way by `<f:validateBean disabled="#{param.validationBean == 'ignore_validation'}" />` without the need for a custom validator.

Comment: Standard bean validation can be bypassed setting `immediate="true"`, don't know if it will work in your case. (Just my two cents.)

Comment: Hi BalusC. Actually, you're right. I created a simpler xhtml page and the parameter did get sent to the request parameter map, causing the validation to be skipped. My problem is that in the actual, more complex, page, this didn't work, for some reason. Any idea what could cause the parameter to be missed? And as for using the validateBean tag, couldn't I have the same problem if the parameter isn't submitted?

Comment: Hi siebzr0r. I'm aware of the 'immediate="true"' effect, but this also causes the process values phase to be skipped, which is something I do not wish, since the values from the page wouldn't be submitted and bound to the managed bean!